# The dog for "Pet the dog" trophy is missing

Tags: achievements, minecraft-dungeons

After the latest update we got a new game mode with a Tower to climb and few more trophies, which I'm trying to get.
One of them asks you to [Pet the dog](https://www.trueachievements.com/a349364/pet-the-dog-achievement) that can be found

> just outside the bridge in the camp

as you can see in this screenshot:

> [image]

The problem is I'm missing that dog, it's just an empty spot in my game.
I thought this was a DLC only feature, but I own the [Ultimate edition](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/dungeons/ultimate-edition) which includes all 6 DLCs.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Reddit, you need to upgrade the Blacksmith to the second stage in order to get the dog. This means beating the Arch-Illager for the first time.

I did it and the dog is there.